# How to judge whether a macro is defined or not while I debug source code using gdb ?

Tags: c, gdb

```
struct tree{
#ifdef A
   #define TREE_GET(x,y)        &x->y
#else
   #define TREE_GET(x,y)        x->y
#endif
};
```

I want to know whether macro A  was defined . Is there any command I can use in gdb .

Comment: How about setting a global variable in addition to defining `TREE_GET`? While you cannot check for `A`, or the definition of `TREE_GET`, you can check for the variable no problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In compilation time we pass the -gdwarf-2 and -g3 flags to ensure the compiler includes information about preprocessor macros in the debugging information.

For example, `g++ -gdwarf-2 -g3 program.cpp -o program`

[C Preprocessor Macros](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html)

Answer (score 2):

Compile using `-g3` and in gdb issue:

```
info macro A
```

---

From the [gcc documentation on -g3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html):

> -glevel
>
> ...
>
> Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro definitions present in the program. Some debuggers support macro expansion when you use -g3.

From the [gdb documenation on `info macro` & friends](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html):

> info macro [-a|-all] [--] macro
>
> Show the current definition or all definitions of the named macro, and describe the source location or compiler command-line where that definition was established. The optional double dash is to signify the end of argument processing and the beginning of macro for non C-like macros where the macro may begin with a hyphen.